# Google cloud speech API streaming: Getting "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: OUT_OF_RANGE: Audio data is being streamed too fast." error on AWS

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We are getting this "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: OUT_OF_RANGE: Audio data is being streamed too fast." error on a application deployed on AWS. However on a local testing environment, this is not re-produceable. Double checked all the configurations (sample rates, language codes etc.), and still getting the error on AWS deployment. Any insights on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Parameters : [Encoding=LINEAR16,Rate=44100]